# How can I manipulate the post date in Ghost using the Momentjs 'add' function

Tags: momentjs, ghost-blog

I've just started a Ghost.org blog and I want the blog post dates to display one year ahead of when they were actually written. I know Ghost uses Moment.js and I am able to adjust formatting (DD MM YYYY, YY MM DD etc...) but it doesn't seem to accept the 'add' function described in the Moment.js [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/).

This is the code I currently have.

```
<time datetime="{{date format="YYYY-MM-DD"}}">
  {{date format='DD MMM YYYY'}}
</time>
```

To be clear, I want the blog post dates to remain accurate in ghost. I simply want to manipulate what gets DISPLAYED to the user as 1 year ahead.

EG. I write a blog post and it's post date is 20th Dec 2013. I want the date on the blog post to DISPLAY 20th Dec 2014.

The Ghost [{{date}}](http://docs.ghost.org/themes/#helpers) helper does not seem to accept the 'add' function.

Any help would be really appreciated. I am still learning javascript, so there may be something obvious I'm missing. I apologise if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a bit late for you but it might help other people.

I found a way to edit the date in the casper view. It's more a hack than a real solution. But I wanted to be able to modify the date language without modifying the core. So here is my solution:

You need to add moment js in the casper template to do so you need to download it on the website and place it in the asset folder.

Place http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js in /content/theme/casper/assets/js/

Then you need to call it in you /content/theme/casper/default.hbs

Add this line at the bottom of the file just before the index.js one.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset "js/moment-with-locales.min.js"}}"></script>
```

Finally add this code in /content/theme/casper/assets/js/index.js just after the line

```
$document.ready(function () {
```

like this :

```
    var dates = $('.post-date');
    var i = 0;
    var postDate = moment();

    for(i=0;i<dates.length;i++){
      postDate = moment(dates.eq(i).html());
      postDate.add(1,'year');
      dates.eq(i).html(postDate.format('LL'));
    }
```